# Android: uploading application draft to one Google Play account, releasing with another?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I'm currently developing an Android application using InApp Billing functionality. In order to perform testing with real end-to-end payment scenarios I need to upload the application draft to Google Play - as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-real).

However, my customer wants to publish the application later using its own Google Play account.

Is it possible, that I upload the draft first, **remove it after testing**, and then my customer releases the application (with the same package name) with a totally different Google Play account? Would Google Play allow for that?

I don't want to mess with package ID, it is annoying (but perhaps safest?).

Comment: To avoid confusion: my customer is about to re-build the app, re-sign with very own private key, and upload&release with own Google Play account. The question boils down to: do they need to also change the application ID (package), even if I remove the never-released draft from my account? Hope that's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering (sort of) my own question:

- it seems perfectly fine to remove the application **draft** from one profile and re-upload to another one
- for the time being I only checked re-uploading APK signed with the same private key
- funny enough, all configured in-app items that I configured for this application on my own profile reappeared after uploading to the second profile!

Answer (score 0):

Nopes, when the applications are export, the are exported and signed with certain certificates and private key, so that if anyone have that private key, the will be able to upload the app with the same identifier, 
i.e.

```
com.yourcompanyname.appname
```

This is unique identifier, identifies your app to update it further.

Comment: I understand applications are signed using my private key. My customer wants to re-build the app with own key, and re-upload it and release under its own account. The question is - would it be possible if I remove the draft (i.e. never released) application from my account. Would that "free" the package ID (which otherwise has to be globally unique)?

Comment: No, I don't think it will release the unique package ID, because it is already uploaded in they system, but unpublished.